# Parse error : bad input on a certain line

Tags: python, parsing, input

Open the file `romeo.txt` and read it line by line. For each line, split the line into a list of words using the `split()` method. The program should build a list of words. For each word on each line check to see if the word is already in the list and if not append it to the list. When the program completes, sort and print the resulting words in alphabetical order.

I keep getting a parse error `bad input on line 7` and I don't know why…

```
fname = input('Enter File Name') 
fh = open(fname) 
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    line = line.split()
    for word in line:
        if word in lst: 
            continue
        else : 
            lst.append(word)
lst.sort()
print(lst)
```

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback in your question

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm unable to reproduce your error. Please check your code and clarify.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have the full error traceback, I'm using a graded assignment tool. It just says "ParseError: bad input on line 7." Do you need the txt file to reproduce the error? https://www.py4e.com/code3/romeo.txt